# How to detect the observable property that was called in manual subscriptions

Tags: knockout.js

Is there any way I can find out the name of the observable property that called a manual subscription?

The callback signature in knockout is `.subscribe(function(newValue) { ... })`  but since I am subscribing to all observable properties of an object I would like to have had a signature like this: `function(newValue, propertyName)` (and possibly an old value...).

The code extract below shows me trying to get a closure around the property but it always comes up still with the last property scanned.

How can I find out which property was changed?

```
this.Data = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataFromServer);
```

...

```
ScrollDataItem.prototype.GetInformedOnChange = function () {
    var self = this;
    for(var prop in this.Data) {
        if(self.Data.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop != "__ko_mapping__") {
            var closureProp = prop;
            self.Data[prop].subscribe(function (newValue) {
                alert("New value is: " + newValue);
                alert("Property that called: " + closureProp);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this is because of hoisting (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/).  The closureProp variable that you declare is scoped to the GetInformedOnChange function.  Variables in javascript are always scoped to the function, not to a `for` or a `while` loop.

Let's walk through what you're seeing.

Suppose you have 2 properties in this.Data: FirstName and LastName.  The first time you go through the `for(var prop in this.Data)` loop, prop is FirstName, and thus closureProp is assigned first name.  The subscription gets set up, but closureProp is not used for anything yet because the thing you are subscribed to has not yet triggered.

The second time you go through the loop, closureProp (the same variable - a new one is NOT created - see the link above on hoisting) is assigned to LastName, and then a subscription to LastName is set up.

Then, supposing the FirstName subscription is triggered, your anonymous function is called that does the alerts.  It uses closureProp, which is assigned to LastName.

You can fix this by adding an extra layer of scoping, i.e., an extra function.  Here is how:

Create a new function to handle the subscribing that provides an extra layer of scope:

```
function subscribeWithName(propName, observable) {
    var closureProp = propName;
    observable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("New value is: " + newValue);
        alert("Property that called: " + closureProp);
    });
}
```

Call this function to set up the subscription:

```
for(var prop in this.Data) {
    if(self.Data.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop != "__ko_mapping__") {
        subscribeWithName(prop, self.Data[prop]);            
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/PfaD7/